# Problem installing package using setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, avro, setup.py, requirements.txt

I have setup.py set to get the dependencies from requirements.txt that I generate from my virtual environment of the project. As follows:

In my venv:

```
pip3 freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then:

```
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    required = f.read().splitlines()

setuptools.setup(
    ...
    install_requires=required,
    ...
)
```

But I have this error displayed when I try to install my package:

```
raise RequirementParseError(str(e))
pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Parse error at "'(===file'": Expected stringEnd
```

So when checking my requirements.txt file, I found this which must be the root cause of package installation failure:

```
avro-python3===file-.avro-VERSION.txt
```

I didn't install it explicitly it is a transitive dependency. And when I try to install avro-python3 it, I get the following error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: avro-python3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (file-.avro-VERSION.txt)
```

What can I do to fix my problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens because the `setup` method is not expecting a version to have the format `file-.avro-VERSION.txt`. I suspect that the character "-" is what bothers the parser, as it expects the string to end instead of that character.

I suggest you try to use one of [the official versions](https://pypi.org/project/avro-python3/#history) on the `requirements.txt` file and the problem should be gone.