# pip install cannot resolve the version from artifactory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, artifactory

When installing using `pip install -r requirement.txt` (it has avro-python3) on a ubuntu machine. I am getting following error, it used to be a warning for a while ago, but now it's resulting in error.

```
Collecting avro-python3==1.9.2.1
  Downloading https://artifactory/avro-python3-1.9.2.1.tar.gz (37 kB)
WARNING: Requested avro-python3==1.9.2.1 from https://artifactory/avro-python3-1.9.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=ca1e77a3da5ac98e8833588f71fb2e170b38e34787ee0e04920de0e9470b7d32 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)), but installing version file-.avro-VERSION.txt
ERROR: Requested avro-python3==1.9.2.1 from  https://artifactory/avro-python3-1.9.2.1.tar.gz#sha256=ca1e77a3da5ac98e8833588f71fb2e170b38e34787ee0e04920de0e9470b7d32 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4)) has different version in metadata: 'file-.avro-VERSION.txt'
```

My requirements.txt looks like

avro-python3==1.9.2.1

Is there a way to avoid this error?

What needs to be fixed in order to resolve it?

Is there a way I can specify in requirement.txt ? to not use artifactory for this package?

Comment: please describe what you are trying to install, what is your system!

Comment: Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223796/problem-installing-package-using-setup-py ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem installing package using setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64223796/problem-installing-package-using-setup-py)

Comment: @DrorBereznitsky this doesn't solve my issue. I am specifying the fixed version, and pip is able to fetch it from artifactory but when installing git says has different version in metadata

Comment: You probably need to update pip and setuptools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I downloaded [`avro-python3-1.9.2.1.tar.gz`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5a/80/acd1455bea0a9fcdc60a748a97dcbb3ff624726fb90987a0fc1c19e7a5a5/avro-python3-1.9.2.1.tar.gz) from *PyPI*. And its `setup.cfg` file looks like:

```
[metadata]
name = avro-python3
version = file: avro/VERSION.txt
description = Avro is a serialization and RPC framework.
...
```

Note the *version* line and the `file:` notation. This notation was added in *setuptools 39.2.0*:

- [doc](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/declarative_config.html#metadata)
- [changelog](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#id338)
- [code change](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/1359)

So, make sure that your *setuptools* version is at least *39.2.0* and it would probably work better (maybe upgrading *pip* could help as well).

Comment: I hit the same problem while trying to install avro. Upgrading setuptools worked for me!